# how to include the Subfig captions below the main figure caption in LaTex?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption, article

I am preparing a manuscript for an IET journal. I have used the following packages for figure:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.,labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=sl,labelsep=quad}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
```

then I used the following code snippet:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\subfloat[Tunneling and thermionic component of current]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{It+Ith}
  \label{It_Ith}
  }
\subfloat[Total drain current]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{Ids}
  \label{I_ds}
  }
\label{I_V}
\caption{I-V characterstics in the subthreshold regime}
\end{figure}
```

and the sub-captions are below the respective figures like this:
[image: present scenario]

But I want the subfig captions to be under the main caption like this:
[image: desired sample]

Note that, all the captions are left aligned and the sub-captions are not italic. How to generate this type of formatting?

Comment: Dear friend, I'm confused why the caption and sub captions are all above the figure in my document when I apply your code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using empty subcaptions and then reference them with `\protect\subref*` within the main caption (the * removes the parantheses - without it, you get (a) instead of a):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.,labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=sl,labelsep=quad}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize,labelformat=simple]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\subfloat[]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{It+Ith}
  \label{It_Ith}
  }
\subfloat[]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{Ids}
  \label{I_ds}
  }
\label{I_V}
\caption{I-V characterstics in the subthreshold regime\\[2ex]
\protect\subref*{It_Ith} \textnormal{Tunneling and thermionic component of current}\\
\protect\subref*{I_ds} \textnormal{Total drain current}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The normal font can be used by `\textnormal`.